# External Accessory Framework EAAccessoryManager connectedAccessories returns only 1 accessory on iOS 4.2 when there should be more

Tags: ios4, ios5, bluetooth, external-accessory

Calling the connectedAccessories method on the EAAccessoryManager returns a list with only a single accessory (seemly randomly chosen from the available connected accessories in the Bluetooth screen) when running on iOS 4.2 using an iPhone 3GS.

In retrospect - on iOS 5.0 on an iPhone 4 the method returns the correct list of accessories (currently tested up to 2). According to the documentation iOS 4.0 should return a *list* of accessories however it fails to mention if this can contain more than one item. (Apparently in iOS 3.0 only one device WAS supported).

The EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification notification is also only fired once for the randomly chosen accessory when running on iOS 4.0; Disabling the accessory results in the appropriate EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotificiation for that accessory. Re enabling the accessory doesn't result in any further notifications without returning to the bluetooth settings menu and re connecting the device (but that's another annoying issue). Visiting the bluetooth connection screen reveals the originally connected accessory no disconnected and my second accessory connected but further calls to the "connectedAccessories" method still returns an empty list.

Viewing the console logs from the phone I can see the bluetooth system connecting and monitoring both devices but somewhere along the line this isn't been presented via the External Accessory Framework.

If anyone has any helpful info on this issue that'd be great -- it seems there's only a small number of iOS developers that have even worked with this framework so finding anything other than copies of the original apple documentation is rather difficult :-D.

To summarise:

Is it possible to detect multiple accessories from iOS and connect and open sessions for multiple devices. I've found this is possible in iOS 5.0 on iPhone 4.

Many thanks,
Chris